# How to write words from a file in an array?

Tags: c#, string, struct

How to write words from a file in an array in c language?

eg: file -> " Hello world "

```
string ->  |Hello|world|
```

positions -----   0     1

Comment: Hello --- position 0

Comment: world ---- position 1

Answer (score 4):

Just read the file and split it.

```
var words = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename).Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read all content from file to array with this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("The file path");
```

It also stores each line from file in array separately.

Comment: You still need to split words in the same line as separate array elements.

Answer (score 0):

You try to read some data, but you don't have anywhere to put it. All you have is 4 pointers, pointing to god knows where and you are trying to write into it!

There are many ways to do this:

1.You know the bound to the size of the data:

```
'#include <stdio.h>
 #define MAX_CHARS 20

 typedef char string[MAX_CHARS+1];  // leave one space for '\0'

 main(){
int i;
string array[4];

FILE *my;
my = fopen("my.txt","r");
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      fscanf(data, "%s", array[i]);  // no need for & with %s
fclose(my);
}'
```